# For loop and Lazyloader

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing a new photo gallery for a website, and I consider the gallery should have some abilities including:

1. Using glob to get only jpg files in specific folder
2. Using lazy loader to improve the performance and loading speed.

The first bit is fairly easy task for me, but when it comes to the second task I am quick confuse.

Since the first function will loop thorough the whole folder and display all .jpg file it contains, I have no idea how to break the loop and resume it when user wants to load more photos.

I have my codes like this at the moment:

```
<html>
    <!--The concept on this widget is to : Check specific folder > Read & Loop thourght the whole folder > Output all the images contain > Lazy loader.
    Therefore user only needs to drag the image in the file when adding new images.!-->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> <!--prevent courrption in IE!-->
    </head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <body>

        <!--------------------Tradional selector!------------>
        <!--<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
        <output id="list"></output>!-->

        <!-------------------drag and drop!----------------->
        <div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
        <output id="list"></output>

        <?php
        foreach (glob("media/images/*.jpg") as $filename) { //glod to get .jpg files
            echo "<img src='$filename' width=auto height='500'/> "; 
        }
        ?>



        <script>
        // Check for the various File API support.
        //validator
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
          // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
         // alert('working');
        } else {
          //alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
        }

        /*=======================standrad file selector====================

         function handleFileSelect(evt) { 
            var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object, MSDN standrad , a selector 

            // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
            var output = []; //This is an empty Array ! the result/output will be store in array 

            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            //The push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.
            //example banana.push | banana is juz a var declare on top .push()is the method
              output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                          f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                          f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                          '</li>');
            }
            //path selector
            document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
          }

          document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

          */
        <!----------------------Drag and drop!---------------------------!>
         function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            event.stopPropagation(); <!--jquery libraries function >
            event.preventDefault(); <!--This method does not accept any arguments. So when you drag the images it will do something else then the default action!-->

            var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

            // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
            var output = [];//This is an empty Array ! the result/output will be store in array 

            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
              output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                          f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                          f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                          '</li>');
            }
                //path selector
            document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
          }

          function handleDragOver(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.

            // ^The DataTransfer object is used to hold the data that is being dragged during a drag and drop operation. 

            /*There's few value rather than copy:

            copy: A copy of the source item is made at the new location.
            move: An item is moved to a new location.
            link: A link is established to the source at the new location.
            none: The item may not be dropped.
            */
          }

          // Setup the dnd listeners.
          var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
          dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
          dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How should i implement lazyloader under this situation?

Comment: You're using php to get the files, why is this tagged javascript/jquery?

Comment: Because my question is about LAZYLOADER the Jquery plugin. Don't understand why haters vote me down with unacceptable reason.

Comment: this actually confused me from the get-go, i thought for a minute you were talking about the lazy loader *design pattern*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of providing an answer, i will assume you are using this plugin : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

make sure your images have a proper **class name** so you can tell jQuery LazyLoader which images to look for :

```
<?php
        foreach (glob("media/images/*.jpg") as $filename) { //glod to get .jpg files
            echo "<img class="lazyLoadMe" src='$filename' width=auto height='500'/> "; 
        }
?>
```

then, at the bottom of your document, add the following:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
       $("img.lazyLoadMe").lazyload();
    });
  </script>
```

this will cause lazyLoader to lazy-load images with the class `"lazyLoadMe"` only.

You do not necessarily need to stop the php loop that writes all the img tags to the document, since lazyLoader will automatically make sure the images are not loaded until they are scrolled into view.

Comment: Wont work for me. It still loads all at the same time.